# Get absolute file path via Java applet or flash

Tags: java, flash, security, applet

I asked a previous question about if it were possible to get the absolute filepath of a file using the html5 file API. Due to browser security issues, it is not.

For an internal project, I need to be able to move files from one computer's machine to shared storage. A 'controller' does the moving, as the user's don't have direct access to the storage volume.

Is it possible to pull the a file's absolute path using flash or a java applet in a browser? If so, how would this be done, or if you could point me to relevant documentation, that would be great.

Comment: It is not possible in Flash/ActionScript (when run in a web browser, in an AIR app it is possible). Flash Player, when running in a web browser, has the same kind of restrictions as the JavaScript file API. You can ask the user to select a file and have your code operate on that file and its content, but you can't get the file path in ActionScript. I believe it is possible from a signed Java applet, but I have no experience with that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trusted applet could provide the information, with a little help from the end user.

Offer the user a `JFileChooser` to navigate to the files/directories of interest.  Once the user has selected a `File`, call [`JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile%28%29) for the details.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to add Policy File permission. Please refer > http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html. Hope that helps

Comment: Policy files are not a viable solution to gaining trust in a 'real world wide web' context.  If the applet needs trust, digitally sign it then encourage the user to accept the digitally signed code.